# Conection to external host from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, database-connection

My local enviroment has connection with a machine that has a BDD. When I ping this machine's IP I have a response.

[image: Standard]

When I sart my container with docker compose, this container doesn't have connection with this machine. If I enter the container with `docker exec -it my-container sh` and I `ping` the DBB machine I have no response.

[image: Standard]

I have docker installed in Windows 10 y my Docker Compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  tomcat:
    image: 'tomcat:7.0.91-jre8-alpine'
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ./warfiles:/home
        - ./conf:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost 
        - ./context.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/context.xml
        - ./ik-report-config:/ik-report-conf
        - ./lib/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc4.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc4.jar
    ports:
        - 8070:8080
        - 8000:8000
    environment:
     - REPORT_ENGINE_HOME=/ik-report-conf
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to use was `network_mode: bridge`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `network_mode: host`.

From the [Docker Network Guide](https://docs.docker.com/network/):

> host: For standalone containers, remove network isolation between the
>   container and the Docker host, and use the host’s networking directly.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I think it could be a `VLAN` problem. Probably `DockerNat` is in a different Vlan than my local environment. I've tried to change it in `Hyper-V`, but everytime I restart Docker Service, `DockerNat` sets to default again.